# Multivariable divergence theorem two cylinder question

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem, divergence-theorem

Let $E$ be the intersection of the cylinders $x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 1, y^{2}+z^{2} \leq 1$. Compute the flux
$$
\begin{align}
& \iint_{\partial E} F \cdot d S \\[6pt]
\text {where } & F=\left(x y^2+\cos (y z)\right) i-\left(x^2+\sin (z x) \right) j+(z+\cos (x y)) k, \text { and } \partial E
\end{align}
$$
is oriented outward.

Any one please help me how to solve it as I totally have no idea how to go with it.

Comment: Write down what the divergence theorem says you must compute and tell us precisely where you get stuck.

Comment: In order you realize the kind of symmetries you can play on, see ["Steinmetz solid""](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinmetz_solid)

Comment: I have solved it but i am not able to upload the picture