# Multivariable divergence theorem bicylinder questiin

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-theorem

Let $E$ be the intersection of the cylinders $x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 1, y^{2}+z^{2} \leq 1$.

Compute flux $ \ \iint_{\partial E} F \cdot d S$

where $\vec F = \left(x y^{2}+\cos (y z)\right) \hat i - \left(x^{2} + \sin (z x)\right) \hat j + (z + \cos (x y)) \hat k \ $ and $ \ \partial E$
is oriented outward.

What I tried:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKZVW.jpg)

Image2:
[image]

Please guide have I got it right.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is exactly the same as the one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4115444) asked 2 hours ago.

Comment: Yeah but there i was not able to show my working i just reposted to show my working

Comment: Why can you not upload your work to the earlier asked question?

Comment: Or if you are not able to edit the earlier question, may be delete that question as it is not yet answered and edit your question here to say you have reposted with your working as you could not edit the previous question with image.

Comment: Also it is important that you learn mathjax and type in your work rather than posting images of your work.

Comment: I closed the other copy as  duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct and your working is correct except one mistake that led to wrong answer.

$\nabla \cdot \vec F = y^2 - 0 + 1 = y^2 + 1$ as you found.

So you are right that the volume integral to find flux is,

$\displaystyle \iiint_E (1+y^2) \ dV \ $, where $E$ is a Steinmetz solid made by intersection of two cylinders $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$ and $y^2+z^2 \leq 1$. Using volume of thin cylindrical slices perpendicular to $y$ axis, the volume integral becomes,

$\displaystyle \iiint_V (1+y^2) \ dV \ = \displaystyle 4 \int_{-1}^1 (1+y^2) (1-y^2) \ dy = \displaystyle 8 \int_0^1  \color {blue} {(1-y^4)} \ dy$

Your mistake: You wrote the integrand as $(1-y^2)$ instead of $(1-y^4)$

Comment: Any reaction or question?